# TPS65217 control and proper power cycle of BeagleBone Black

Tags: debian, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

We spotted situation with BeagleBone where by some strange situation Ethernet PHY freezes and warm power cycle won't bring that back. It happens usually when you switch the board on which Ethernet cable is being unplugged. The device must operate remotely.

What should have help is proper power reset of TPS65217. Unfortunately the "reboot" command resets only linux by itself. It doesn't proceed proper reset sequence, i.e. ask TPS65217 to put RESET line low. While warm reboot this line stays high so Ethernet PHY cant' be reset.

Did anybody came a cross method to speak to TPS65217 by I2C and ask it for "proper RESET"?

According to the datasheet of TPS65217, I sent to password register XOR SEQ6 register and next the value I want to send. I though that SEQDWN or SEQUP can do the job. But I am simply not sure is linux permits you to save a data to it and if it does how it is executed.

I use i2ctools to speak to the chip, e.g.
sudo i2cget -y -f 0 0x24 0x0B //read out 
i2cset -y -f 0 0x24 0x0B 0x6302 -w //write password and new value of 0x1E register.

Thanks for help

Comment: You might want to talk to *zmatt* on freenode IRC channel `#beagle`. He's spent a lot of time looking into AM335x and BBB glitches and how to deal with them.

Comment: @MarcinGajewski, were you able to solve this problem? I currently have the same problem, and I don't have a solution.

Comment: We applied two solutions:
1. The faulty bit in ETH PHY seems to be Power Save mode. Occasionally the PHY won't wake up while data trasmits begans. The most efficient way was disabling the sleep mode (comment it out) and recomplining the kernel.
2. We went for the proper Watchdog. You can make a script that freezes the Watchdog GPIO line and by this "forces" a proper reset.